# VBA Vloopup using 2 different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have to get some information from 1 Workbook to another by using a Vlookup. The reason is that I got 75 cells that need to be filled with prices from another workbook but there will not always be 75 prices in the other workbook.

```
Sub Update()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

' Open Workbook "Verzamelstaat" '
rowl = ActiveCell.Row
linkl = Cells(rowl, 16).Value
Application.Workbooks.Open (linkl)
Filenamel = Mid(linkl, InStrRev(linkl, "\") + 1, Len(linkl))
Set wb2 = Workbooks(Filenamel)

' Copy data to other workbook '

wb1.Sheets(1).Range("AY4").Value = Application.VLookup(wb1.Sheets(1).Range("AY2").Value, wb2.sheets(1).Range("A:A"), 2, False)

' Close Workbook "Verzamelstaat" '
Workbooks(Filenamel).Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

The problem I have is that `wb1.Sheets(1).Range("AY4")` ends up as #REF!.

The value of AY2 = 001 and the other workbook has 001 to 075 in column A.

I think the answer is simple but I just don't see it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the second parameter of your `VLookUp function` that it refers to both A and B columns:

```
... = Application.VLookup(wb1.Sheets(1).Range("AY2").Value, wb2.sheets(1).Range("A:B"), 2, False)
```