# How to define range in VLOOKUP, using different sheets and variables in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Doing a VLOOKUP function i use 1 column from sheet1 and 2 columns from sheet "Files" inside the same workbook. I have a problem with defining range from sheet called "Files":

```
Sub VLOOKUP()
Dim Dept_Row, Dept_Clm As Long
Dim LastRowA, LastRowB As Long
Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
ctr = 0
LastRowB = currentsheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowA = Sheets("Files").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Table1 = currentsheet.Range("B11:B" & LastRowB)
Table2 = Sheets("Files").Range("A1:A" & LastRowA)

Dept_Row = currentsheet.Range("F11").Row
Dept_Clm = currentsheet.Range("F11").Column
For Each cl In Table1
currentsheet.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4], Files!R1C1:R & LastRowA & Files!C2, 2, False)"
Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
ctr = ctr + 1
Next cl

'Sal = Application.VLOOKUP(currentsheet.Range("B11").Value, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Files").Range("$A$1:$B$" & LastRowA), 1, False)

 End Sub
```

The problem appears at line `currentsheet.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4], Files!R1C1:R & LastRowA & Files!C2, 2, False)"`

or

`Sal = Application.VLOOKUP(currentsheet.Range("B11").Value, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Files").Range("$A$1:$B$" & LastRowA), 1, False)`.

I found similar topics here:
[Using VBA to enter a vlookup function in a cell using user chosen file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529549/using-vba-to-enter-a-vlookup-function-in-a-cell-using-user-chosen-file)
and
[VBA Vloopup using 2 different workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012262/vba-vloopup-using-2-different-workbooks)

But did not manage to make it work. Maybe someone could help, how to define range in the right way, using different Sheets and LastRow as a variable? Thanks!

Comment: I would use a full reference to `Rows`. When used as `Rows` it refers to the `Activesheet` of the `Activeworkbook`. You might want to try `currentsheet.Rows` instead, and the same for the other sheet. Also, your `Dept_Row` and `Last_Row` variables are actually `Variant`, not `Long`.. You might want to declare them explicitly as `Long`. One more thing: I hope the actual `Sub` name is not `VLOOKUP()`? :)

Comment: Thanks! I will try to test it. :) about Sub name, ahhah, no, it's just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `LastRowA` inside a string

```
currentsheet.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4], Files!R1C1:R & LastRowA & Files!C2, 2, False)"
```

which should have been:

```
currentsheet.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4], Files!R1C1:R" & LastRowA & "C2, 2, False)"
```

Comment: May I ask how to write in a correct way the function, if I use: Sal = Application.VLOOKUP(currentsheet.Range("B11").Value, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Files").Range("$A$1:$B$" & LastRowA), 1, False) ?